# Does iPhone and iPad support for three, four finger touch gestures?

Tags: iphone, ipad, touch

I wanted to know does iPhone and iPad gives support for three and four finger touch?                                                                                                                                                                                I have browsed a lot but i do get information only for Mac book touch pad for three and four finger
If iPhone/ iPad supports three and four finger touch what are the gestures supported?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the iPhone, but the iPad supports up to 11 simultaneous touches, as detailed by [Matt Gemmell](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/05/09/ipad-multi-touch)!

Comment: Heh, you managed to post that while I was rooting around looking for the video URL. Deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My iPhone 3G supports tracking a maximum of 5 simultaneous touches.

Answer (score 0):

Osmose (IPhone/iPad app) supports three finger simultaneous touch. So it's at least that much.

Answer (score 0):

> If iPhone/ iPad supports three and four finger touch what are the gestures supported?

Both support at least 4 Touches. Though there are no gestures for 4 fingers, you might have 2 pinch-gestures going on at the same time.
In my experience I'd still advise to limit the amount of possible touches, especially if you're using the "touchesBegan/touchesMoved/touchesEnded". (Just throw away the third, forth touch, when you already have 2)

Imagine two simultanuous pinches on the same image, since both essentially define a transform, the image will constantly jump between the two transforms!

Also additional touches could just be random fingers that landed on the screen accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

Both are multitouch devices. The number of simultaneous touches supported on both is different though.

About gestures:

Apple only supplies you with callback methods such as touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded. Look these methods up in the docs. They provide you with ways to count number of touches, taps, and also track finger movements. There are no "standard" gestures. Only what you code in.

Some standard library objects support multitouch gestures such as pinch and zoom (the UIScrollView for example) but the reason is that they are standard objects created by Apple.

If you want to make gestures, you have to code them in. For example, to do pinch and zoom, you need to use touchesMoved with two finger touches and calculate the distance between the two coordinates.

To get into the detail of these algorithms for gestures would be overkill so would you like me to outline a few?

Comment: as of 3.2 there are gesture recognizers (UIGestureRecognizer).